# How to use logistic regression on test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, kaggle

I am using Logistic Regression on my Titanic model and PyCharm is asking me to pass DataFrames with bool values only:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Titanic-Kaggle/TItanic-Kaggle.py", line 29, in <module>
    predictions = logReg.predict(test[test_data])
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2914, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_frame(key)
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3009, in _getitem_frame
    raise ValueError('Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only')
ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only
```

I don't understand why because the exact same features were used on Logistic Regression while training the model and it was well received then.  Here is my code (ignore the code repetition. That's a problem I'm going to tackle after):

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)

train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/test.csv")

train['Sex'] = train['Sex'].replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1])
train['Embarked'] = train['Embarked'].replace(['C', 'Q', 'S'], [1, 2, 3])
train['Age'].fillna(train.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)
train['HasCabin'] = train['Cabin'].notnull().astype(int)
train['Relatives'] = train['SibSp'] + train['Parch']
train_data = train[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Relatives', 'Fare', 'Age', 'Embarked', 'HasCabin']]
x_train, x_validate, y_train, y_validate = train_test_split(train_data, train['Survived'], test_size=0.22, random_state=0)

test['Sex'] = test['Sex'].replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1])
test['Embarked'] = test['Embarked'].replace(['C', 'Q', 'S'], [1, 2, 3])
test['Age'].fillna(test.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)
test['HasCabin'] = test['Cabin'].notnull().astype(int)
test['Relatives'] = test['SibSp'] + test['Parch']
test_data = test[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Relatives', 'Fare', 'Age', 'Embarked', 'HasCabin']]

logReg = LogisticRegression()
logReg.fit(x_train, y_train)

predictions = logReg.predict(test[test_data])
submission = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId': test['PassengerId'], 'Survived': predictions})

filename = 'Titanic-Submission.csv'
submission.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Specifically, Python takes issue with this snippet:

```
test_data = test[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Relatives', 'Fare', 'Age', 'Embarked', 'HasCabin']]

...

predictions = logReg.predict(test[test_data])
```

**UPDATE**

I've changed my `predictions` variable to this:

`predictions = logReg.predict(test_data)`

And now this is my stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Titanic-Kaggle/TItanic-Kaggle.py", line 29, in <module>
    predictions = logReg.predict(test_data)
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 281, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 257, in decision_function
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 573, in check_array
    allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 56, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Which means that my feature selection/engineering for the test data does not go through

Comment: `logReg.predict(test_data)` - just give test_data, You have already selected the necessary columns/features from test, so just pass test_data

Comment: @Backtrack see that's a problem too because I get this error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'S'`, which means that my feature engineering for the Test data didn't go through even though I clearly swapped categorical data for numerical ones.

Comment: Nvm that error.  I've fixed it but if you don't mind, take a look at the edit.

Comment: now the actual problem is you have Null value in dataset. You can do a fix like this, `test_data.dropna(axis=0)` before the prediction

Comment: I shouldn't have to do that.  I am already taking care of the null value (check the code above)

Comment: can you tell me in which line you are doing that ?

Comment: you are going fillna only for Age. Also from the error i am still thinking that the input has Null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predictions with `x_validate` work no problem. Try:

```
>>> predictions = logReg.predict(x_validate)
```

So there must be something wrong with `test_data`. Get some information on the dataframes and compare:

```
>>> x_validate.info(verbose=True)                                                                                                                                                          
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 197 entries, 495 to 45
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Pclass       197 non-null int64
Sex          197 non-null int64
Relatives    197 non-null int64
Fare         197 non-null float64
Age          197 non-null float64
Embarked     197 non-null int64
HasCabin     197 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(5)
memory usage: 12.3 KB

>>> test_data.info(verbose=True)                                                                                                                                                           
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 418 entries, 0 to 417
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Pclass       418 non-null int64
Sex          418 non-null int64
Relatives    418 non-null int64
Fare         417 non-null float64
Age          418 non-null float64
Embarked     418 non-null int64
HasCabin     418 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(5)
memory usage: 22.9 KB
```

Looks like there's a NaN here:

```
Fare         417 non-null float64
```

Comment: Okay I solved it.  Thank you very much.  But I have a question (don't want to make an entire post about this).  `LogisticRegression.score` gave me 83.76% accuracy but Kaggle reduced that number to 76%.  Would you know why that might be the case?

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos first of all, each result in these models depends on an initial random seed, I guess if you run your script several times you will also get different results. Also, you do not know on what dataset Kaggle tests the algorithms so this also accounts for variability in the accuracy results.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thank you.\

Answer (score 1):

You have a `NaN` value in the `Fare` column which you don't take care of. Replacing it similar as you do to `Age` takes care of the problem. Is this the best solution for the model? That's a different argument but this gets rid of the problem.

```
train['Fare'].fillna(train.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)
test['Fare'].fillna(train.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)
```